# Retrieve multiple list from grandchild entity using lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I've three entities, say Parent, Child & GrandChild. This GrandChild has got three lists(a,b & c).

How to retrive all these lists using "Include" in Entity Framework?

I can retrive one list like this:  Include("Parent.Child.GrandChild.a"),

but when I add another Include like :  Include("Parent.Child.GrandChild.b"), it throws an error.

How will i retrive all these lists in a single query?

My code is as follows:

```
objUserNew = objContaxt.ContextRegistration
             .Include("listing.postlist.commentslist")
             .Include(‌​"listing.postlist.taglist")
             .Include("listing.postlist.knocklist")
             .FirstOrDefault(‌​x => x.id == objUser.id);

public class registration
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public forgtPass forgtPass { get; set; }
    public List<listing> listing { get; set; }
}

public class listing
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public List<post> postlist { get; set; }
}

public class post
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string imgUrl { get; set; }
    public List<tag> taglist { get; set; }
    public List<comments> commentslist { get; set; }
    public List<knoqs> knoqs { get; set; }
}

public class tag
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class comments
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public status status { get; set; }
}

public class knoqs
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public virtual int registration_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("registration_id")] public registration registration { get; set; }
    public status status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code so that we can reproduce the problem and help you more.

Comment: objUserNew = objContaxt.ContextRegistration.Include("listing.postlist.commentslist").Include("listing.postlist.taglist").Include("listing.postlist.knocklist").FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == objUser.id);

Comment: public class registration
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public forgtPass forgtPass { get; set; } 
        public List<listing> listing { get; set; }

    }

Comment: public class listing
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public List<post> postlist { get; set; }


    }

Comment: public class post
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string imgUrl { get; set; }
        public List<tag> taglist { get; set; }
        public List<comments> commentslist { get; set; }
        public List<knoqs> knoqs { get; set; }

    }

Comment: public class tag
    { 
        public string name { get; set; } 
    }

Comment: public class comments
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public status status { get; set; }
    }

Comment: public class knoqs
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public virtual int registration_id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("registration_id")]
        public registration registration { get; set; }
        public status status { get; set; }
    }

Comment: You should **EDIT** your question with *edit* button under your question instead of showing your code with comments.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help others help you, please always include your code *in the body of your question,* neatly formatted for readability, and remember that you always have the ability to edit your own posts to add information when necessary.